# Android Wearable -how to filter for specific node

Tags: android, wear-os

I have a mobile app and im sending a message to a wearable.  The code to send the message to the wearable looks like this:

```
private void sendMessage( final String path, final String text ) {
        new Thread( new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes( mApiClient ).await();
                for(Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
                    MessageApi.SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(
                            mApiClient, node.getId(), path, text.getBytes() ).await();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

my question is regarding nodes. Lets say i wanted to send to a particular node.  Lets say a android watch. But i only want to send to android watches not other nodes How would i filter the message.   I am assuming a node means a wearable device.  I notice there is a node.getId() but i dont know what its used for. My end goal is to only broadcast to a specific node/device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [CapabilityApis](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/CapabilityApi); it was created for exactly that reason. Take a look at this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html).